# How to call PayPal API in mobile

Tags: objective-c, paypal, ios9

I am facing problem to use paypal Api in my app. I used the below code    and paypal page is loaded fine but after cancel the payment or success payment. it will redirect to the seller's website and remain in the webview. For loading the paypal page i used webview.

But, i want in my app that after cancel the payment show a popup that your transaction is cancelled and then come back in my app after  clicking on the ok button by closing the webview.
    and after success show that your payment is successful and then again come back in my app after clicking on the ok button by closing the webview.

[image]

```
 paypalId = @"info@guider.com";
    paymentStatus = @"http://www.guider.com";
    cancelWebView = @"http://www.guider.com";
    currencyCode = @"USD";
    country = @"USA";
    cmd = @"_xclick";
    title = @"Ms";
    language = @"EN";



NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=%@&return=%@&cancel_return=%@&language=%@&title=%@&first_name=%@&last_name=%@&country=%@&cmd=%@&amount=%@&custom=%@&item_name=%@&package_id=%@&user_id=%@&currency_code=%@&address1=%@&address2=%@&city=%@&state=%@&zip=%@",paypalId,paymentStatus,cancelWebView,language,title,_firstName,_lastName,country,cmd,_total,_bookingID,_packageName,_packageId,_userId,currencyCode,_address1,_address2,_city,_state,_zipCode];


NSLog(@"credential prnt: %@", urlString);


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
 _webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```